# Azure Cognitive Search with boolean field

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Cognitive Search to basically host a Lucene search for me, and I'm using the C# interface for most things.

My document that I'm indexing has several boolean fields.   Using the "Full" search syntax you can search individual fields using the syntax `MyField:"value"` or `MyField:("value1", "value2").

But what I cannot figure out is how to search on boolean fields.  For example: `MyBooleanField:"True"` does not work, nor does `MyBooleanField:"true"`.

My error is: `Illegal arguments in query request: MyBooleanField is not a searchable field`

The class is defined like this:

```
public class MyDocument 
{
    [SimpleField(IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true, IsFacetable = true)]
    public bool MyBooleanField { get; set; }
}
```

Have any of you figured this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean fields are not full-text searchable. You can use filters to match on them:

> GET /indexes('myindex')/docs?$filter=MyBooleanField eq true&api-version=2020-06-30

Using the .NET SDK, you can set the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchoptions.filter?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Search_Documents_SearchOptions_Filter) property on `SearchOptions` to an [OData filter expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter), in this case `"MyBooleanField eq true"`.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean fields aren't searchable so you can't reference them in your search expression.

Instead, you should use [filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-filters) to scope down the search results. In your case, the syntax would be:

```
$filter=MyBooleanField eq true
```

This link also has some additional details and helpful examples:
[OData $filter syntax in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter)